# Sigtrap with only one free in code

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

So here is my problem, I have created this struct:

```
typedef struct foo *fooPtr;
struct foo {
foo2Ptr node;
foo3Ptr node;
char *Random;
};

fooNew(char* String) {
    int StringLength;
    StringLength = strlen(String) + 1;
    Newfoo = (fooPtr *)malloc(sizeof(fooPtr));
    Newfoo->Random = (char*)malloc(StringLength * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(Newfoo->Random, String);
    /*Rest of foo members initialized below....*/
}

fooChangeRandom(fooPtr Foo, String) {
    int StringLength;
    StringLength = strlen(String) + 1;
    free(Foo->Random);
    Foo->Random = (char*)malloc(StringLength * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(Foo->Random, String);
}
```

But whenever I try to print the new string I get random characters. As I recall C requires me to free everything I allocate with malloc, calloc, or realloc so how does Random change when the fooNew ends? Tried to debug and at free I get the SIGTRAP error, on the line that free() gets used, however this is the only dynamically allocated object I have created and I haven't used free before. So Is there something I am missing or something wrong with the syntax of malloc or free?

Comment: Where do you get SIGTRAP? You should be able to pinpoint the line or the function at least which causes it.

Comment: When it reaches the free function, sry thought i had mentioned it, editing now

Comment: Change `malloc(StringLength * sizeof(char)` to `malloc((StringLength+1) * sizeof(char)` or just `malloc(StringLength+1)`. You need one more byte to store terminating zero character.

Comment: Actually it was what pras said, but I ve still to get what the mistake was, I had tried that but since it is an assignment I don't want to get everything ready, so I wrote some pseudo code just to make the problem obvious, I will edit it though, thanks

Comment: all that casting of `malloc` return values can only hurt you

Comment: And rather, do not use typedefs to declare pointer types.

Comment: In any case, this is not a [MVCE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct

```
Newfoo = (fooPtr *)malloc(sizeof(fooPtr));
```

to

```
Newfoo = (fooPtr *)malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
```

Comment: So my mistake was allocating pointer to struct instead of the struct node itself?

Comment: the return value should also be of type `fooPtr`.